# Find $\max( a_{1} a_{2} ... a_{m} )$ where $\sum_{i=1}^{m} a_{i} = 1976$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

If $a_{1}, ..., a_{m}$ positive integers and $ \sum_{i=1}^{m} a_{i} = 1976$, find $\max( a_{1} a_{2} ... a_{m} )$.

---

Attempt:

Notice by AM-GM:
$$ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{m} a_{i} = 1976}{m} \ge (a_{1} a_{2} ... a_{m})^{1/m} $$

So if $m$ is held fixed, then $a_{1}a_{2}...a_{m}$ is maximized if $a_{1} = ... = a_{m}$ (when possible that $1976$ is divisible by $m$).

Using "algorithmic" approach, start with largest possible $m=1976$ and move backwards:

Let $F(m)$ be $\max(a_{1}...a_{m})$ and we find $F$ for each case $m$.

$m=1976$ then
$$F = 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot ... \cdot 1$$

$m=1975$ then we remove one $a_{i}$ from the $m=1976$ case, choose the smallest one to get
$$ F  = 2 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot ...  \cdot 1$$

$m=1974$ then we remove the smallest value from the previous case above, and then distribute it to the other $1974$ numbers. Add to $2$? or add two $1$? pay attention to $a_{i}=2$ and $a_{j}=1$, if we add 1 to either one of them, the total will always be $4$, so by AM-GM $a_{i}a_{j}$ is maximized when both are equal. So we add $1$ to the $a_{j}=1$.

$$ F = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 \cdot ... \cdot 1 = 4$$

continuing this, one see that $F$ increasing as $m$ decrease until $m=988$ we get

$$ F(988) = 2^{988}$$

next, if $m=987$:

we must remove one $2$ from the case $m=988$ and distribute it to the other $987$ numbers. $2$ can be distributed to at most two $a_{i}$s, so the sum of two numbers. So by AM-GM $F$ is maximized when the two $a_{i}$s are equal, so we must have

$$F(987) = 3^{2} 2^{985} $$

and we see $F(987) > F(988)$ because $3^{2} > 2^{3}$. Continuing this, $F(987) < F(986) < ... < F(659)$ because of same reason $3^{2} > 2^{3}$. We have

$$F(659) = 3^{658} 2 $$

---

But after this, we can see $F(658)$ is less than $F(659)$. How to prove (or disprove) that $3^{658} 2$ is the maximum?

---

2nd attempt:

$F(658) = 4^{2} 3^{656}$ this is less than $F(659)$. Then let us view the 1st five terms in

$$(4 + 4 + 3 + 3 + 3) + ... $$

if we distribute a $3$ into the 5 numbers, no matter how we do it we will have the sum equal $20$, and the multiplication of the 5 numbers is maximized when all are equal, so

$$ F(657) = 4^{5} 3^{652} $$ and this is less than $F(658)$ because $3^{4} > 4^{3}$. Continuing until $m = 494$
$$F(494) = 4^{494}$$

and $F(657) > F(656) > ... > F(494)$ because $3^{4} > 4^{3}$.

So far we still have $F(659)$ as the largest.

Comment: You have shown there are at most two numbers below 3.  Can you show there are no numbers above 4?

Comment: @Empy2 what do you mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum of $a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdots a_n$ given $a_1 + \cdots + a_n = 1000$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2171746/maximum-of-a-1-cdot-a-2-cdots-a-n-given-a-1-cdots-a-n-1000). Although the sum is different here, the procedures shown there are basically all independent of any specific value, so they apply to $1976$ as well.

Comment: Note another essentially duplicate question is [Find $max(\prod{a_i})$ given that $\sum a_i=2017$ for $n$ number of positive integers from $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2267150/602049).

Comment: If there is a 6  what could you replace it with? How about other numbers higher than 4?

Comment: @Empy2 I know now. $5 = 2+3$, and $(2)(3)$ is bigger than $5$. $6 = 3+3$ but $(3)(3)$ is bigger. If $a_{i} > 6$ then $a_{i} = 2k +1$ (or $2k$). But $2^{k} > 2k$ for those, so better pick $a_{i}$s without $5,6,7,...$